# The constructor RemoteWebDriver(Capabilities) refers to the missing type Capabilities

Tags: android, testing, appium

I am using Appium for android.
I am trying to set DesiredCapabilities like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
         capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
           capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.gauravdubey.gdlearning");  
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.gauravdubey.gdlearning.MainActivity");
```

(The lines below give the error - The constructor RemoteWebDriver(Capabilities) refers to the missing type Capabilities)

```
WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

However the defintion asks for the same thing- one Url obejct and one of Desired Capabilities. 
I cannot find what the exact problem is.

**UPDATE:**
I tried by changing **RemoteWebDriver** to **AndroidDriver** - but it then says:
The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
***The dependencies added are*** :
• Java-client-2.1.0.jar
• Selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar

Comment: Instead of remove driver , you should use  `driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), capabilities);`

Comment: @HelpingHands thnx for prompt reply. It now says: The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files . Is any dependency to be added explicitly again for this?

Comment: Did you import client JARs to project?

Comment: I have added these two. any else required?
• Java-client-2.1.0.jar
• Selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar

Comment: you should import `java-client-2.2.0` ,`java-client-2.2.0-javadoc`,`java-client-2.2.0-sources`. And also Selenium JARs `selenium-java-2.46.0`,`selenium-java-2.46.0-srcs`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97252/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-answerdroid).

Comment: Actually version may be anything but you need all 3 Java client JARs. but better to use latest.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired capabilities should be following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities()
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, browserName)
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, version)
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, platformName)
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName)
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, deviceID)
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appLocationPath)
        def URL remoteAddress = new URL("http://$hubIP:4444/wd/hub")
        this.androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(remoteAddress, capabilities)
```

And you must have dependency of `io.appium:java-client:3.2.0`.
Should work this way (working for me).

**UPDATE:**
Found out that `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:<version>` dependency is missing. It can be added with `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:<version>` or `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:<version>`.

Comment: thnx fr your answer.I guess its a groovy code. I wrote equivalent java code. and urfortunately at the new AndroidDriver().. line got this error again:The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: I am not using maven. So which jar file to include? I have added selenium-remote-client-2.0a2.jar,selenium-api-2.43.1.jar but not working yet.thanks

Comment: Well if you do not use Maven by the IDE then you must search in their repository and download/add manually.

Answer (score -1):

Remove Selenium jars from your build path. Only add java-client jar to build path.

With that you can use below capabilities in your java code . I am using same capabilities in my java project.

```
    File app = new File("absolute-apk-path-of-your-app");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"your-device-android-version");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"your-device-id");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app);
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","your-device-name");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "your-app-pckg-name");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "your-app-activity");
    capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "your-app-wait-activity-if-app-has");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: This is false. If you look more carefully to the stack-trace of the problem you see that it is the Selenium library that is missing (`org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder`).